# facing isue in UDP multicasting after changing ip of the device

Tags: linux, networking, c, embedded, udp

we have a requirement for UDP multicasting in our project using Linux 4.1 kernel with static ip address.

basic UDP multicasting using sendto function to send data is working fine with device static ip 10.13.204.100, issue comes when i change ip of the device to 10.13.204.101 or any other ip in the same series, the udp multicasting is showing an error

```
sendto: network unreachable
```

im initializing the UDP as shown below

```
int udp_init()
{
    char multicastTTL = 10;
    // Create UDP socket:
    memset(&socket_desc, 0, sizeof(socket_desc));
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (socket_desc < 0)
    {
        perror("socket");
        return 1;
    }
    udp_socket_fd = socket_desc;
    printf("udp_socket_fd=>%d\nsocket_desc==>%d\n", udp_socket_fd, socket_desc);

    /* Set the TTL (time to live/hop count) for the send */
    // if (setsockopt(socket_desc, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_TTL, &multicastTTL, sizeof(multicastTTL)) < 0)
    if (setsockopt(socket_desc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &multicastTTL, sizeof(multicastTTL)) < 0)
    {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr)); /* Zero out structure */
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(EXAMPLE_GROUP); // INADDR_ANY;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(EXAMPLE_PORT);             // htons(udp_port);

    // bind to receive address
    //
    if (bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("bind");
        printf("line %s-->%s:%d\n", __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

once the ip is changed im closing the UDP socket using

```
close(socket_desc)
```

once again im using the udp_init function to initialize the UDP then im sending using sendto function to transmit the data but im get `sendto:network unreachable`

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide the output of `ip address` and `ip route` commands please ?
Are both devices on the same LAN or is there some routing achieved between ?